# ros log: "Shutdown request received [user request] " , what it means

Tags: ros, rosout, ros-kinetic, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[33m[ WARN] [1571817304.679612403]: Shutdown request received.[0m
[33m[ WARN] [1571817304.679718067]: Reason given for shutdown: [user request][0m
release communication

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337563/ros-log:-%22shutdown-request-received-%5Buser-request%5D-%22-,-what-it-means/) by [942951641@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/38911/942951641@qq.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it looks like that this log from ros master, isnot it ?

---

Originally posted by [942951641@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/38911/942951641@qq.com/) with karma: 16 on 2019-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0